# Sending email with nothing but jpg file as body?

Tags: email, jpeg

A client I do some database work for wants to send an email blast to customers. It's a newsletter. He's prepared it in GIMP and sent it to me as just a jpg. Apart from the fact that the links in it won't work, what other reasons should I give him that this isn't a good idea. My list so far is:

1. Thunderbird (and maybe other clients) will block the jpg, so they'll see nothing at all.
2. It'll look terrible on smartphones.
3. Might raise spam blocking issues.

It doesn't seem there's any sort of GIMP to HTML type convertor.

Thanks

Comment: Technically you could place the image in a image tag as 100% width to make it fluid to the device width, but maybe you should omit that as not to encourage a really bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You've pretty much summed it up.

1. The majority of email clients will block the image and see nothing. People will just delete it.
2. The file size will be huge for the email, and most clients will not receive/block for spam. (Images over 30k are a bit risky, so try and keep it below).
3. Considering it will be a non-responsive layout as an image, as you said it will look horrible on SmartPhones.
4. If people do mark it as spam, then that's really bad for any future email campaigns your client will want to run.
5. No Links, targeting client needs and specifics across the entire email won't work.

In all, emails need to be sent as HTML emails.